# Captive AIR application causes default web browser to launch when AIR app launched from OS icon

Tags: windows, air

I have used NSIS to create an installer for an AIR application everything installs properly. As part of the installation I create a custom protocol like "MyVeryOwnApp://" so that if the user clicks an icon on a specific website it will launch the application.

The installer also creates a start menu and desktop icon. When installing on a "clean" machine, Windows 10, no other apps installed, everything works as it should.

On other Windows 10 computers including all of the development machines, when the application is launched the default web browser is also launched. This also occurs when launching the application from the Flash Builder 4.6 IDE.

I need to find out the cause so that I can either keep it from happening when I deploy the application, or at a minimum be able to explain to users what the issues are.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem.

The cause was there was mxml code left over to set the browser focus into the main module. It looked like;

```
<utils:JavaScript>
    <![CDATA[
        function setBrowserFocus()
        {
          Main.focus();
        }
    ]]>
</utils:JavaScript>
```

This evidently caused AIR to instantiate a new instance of the default browser.

I removed the code as it is no longer needed.